# How to connect my modem(Cricket Broadband) to my router(Netgear g54)?

Tags: usb

I have a Cricket Broadband card modem(looks like a flash drive stick) which plugs into a USB port and a Netgear g54 wireless router with Ethernet ports only, how do i connect my modem to the router?

Comment: I tried to find a reverse usb to ethernet adapter but I guess there is no such thing?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can't.

If you want to use a 3g dongle as your internet source, you need to buy a 3G/USB router.

[image]

Comment: That was my experience as well although the 3g/USB router was not very expensive in the UK.

Comment: @Col yep... 3G/USB only (e.g. not dual wan) routers are about £30-£40, and/or you can get 3g modem routers (ones that you put the usim directly in to) for around £70-£90

Comment: thank you guys so much, i will check to see where i can get one, if not i have a guy that can make a reverse usb to ethernet adapter for me i think.

Comment: @Ashley Brown Are you sure? ... Not sure one exists :/ That would basically be a non wireless version of what I showed above - it needs to be a device capable of dialing out (a 3g stick whilst complex, is basically a modem to a machine), and I haven't seen one before that wasn't a router.

Comment: I mean just an adapter plug, like an extension, one end with a usb port and the other end to plug into an ethernet port.

Comment: Yeah I understood that... I really don't think one exists! ... You can get Male USB to Ethernet which is just a USB Network adapter, but, you need a female USB to ethernet - which, I just don't think exists!

Comment: They don't unless you have one custom made.

Comment: @Ashley Brown - I don't think you understand what I am saying... It is a lot more complicated than splicing a cable together! I can easily put a USB port that is connected to a ethernet socket... but... it wouldn't work! ... Again, unless you can show me otherwise!

Comment: thats what i thought too but he says he can make one, idk, i think i can just set up internet connection sharing and avoid the router, i'm trying that now